# Batch file for mouse click

Tags: command-line, batch-file

Hi I want to login to a server automatically. For that I need a batch file that will handle mouse clicks and logs into the system depending on pixels of the server. Can anyone give an example for this?

Thank you.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Well you've asked 11 questions & had accepted 3 answers. hence 30%

Comment: We expect you to have attempted to solve this problem by yourself rather than asking the community to arrive at a complete solution for you. When you've got some code to show us that demonstrates some effort by you (even if it's wrong) please update your question and flag to re-open. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that in batch. Unless you are just calling a low level program in the script that does this, or P/Invoking DLL's from C# (question tagged with C#?).

If you want the server to log in automatically when it boots up, you can modify values in this registry key

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon`

You need to set `AutoAdminLogon` to `1`. Then set `DefaultUsername` and `DefaultPassword` accordingly.

This batch file will set those keys (requires admin rights)

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "AutoAdminLogon" /d "1" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DefaultUsername" /d "yourusername" /f
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon" /v "DefaultPassword" /d "yourpassword" /f
```

Comment: Well that is a server which i am gonna log in. I dont want manual connection(login) for that.